# Android Development with Eclipse which folders to backup before updating

Tags: android, eclipse, backup, development-environment

Google seems to be releasing new versions for their APIs and support libraries frequently. As a new developer I am **scared that an upgrade will eventually break my app or development environment**. So I was wondering which folders should one backup before upgrading or adding another SDK API piece.

I am using Linux, ATM I have these folders I think needs to be backed up:

```
/home/username/android   (where you installed android)
/home/username/ndk   (where NDK is installed)
/opt/eclipse    (where eclipse is installed)
```

It seems a bit overkill are there a few specific folders in the android folder that is susceptible to being overwritten? As many of the folders like andoid/system-images, android/addons etc are partioned by the different versions but some sub-folders like tools, platform-tools, google/extras/licensing aren't.

Does anyone have a smaller list of folders to backup before doing updates. And has anyone successfully restored their backup after suffering from major issues after an upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is a necessary to back up these files or folders since I haven't faced a single issue till this point due to an SDK/NDK update. But as an SDK update happens, generally the folder `<sdk-directory./platform` is updated. There is not much overwriting or such things, but a new API platform will be added to the SDK, generally as a new folder.

Also, if you are on Linux, just like me, I would suggest you to install the eclipse package from the repository and setup the SDK as per the documentation available on Google Developers. Also, for your info, and SDK update wont touch any eclipse files as such. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think backup is really needed. But if you want really back up, follow this.When you download ADT bundle as a whole. Go to SDK folder and backup the platforms folder and the Build Tools folder. This are the main folders which contains the platform files.You can carry on with your update .

And no need to backup Android or NDK or eclipse folders.